# HDP2.5 Hortonworks Sandbox Forgot and Reset root user password

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I was going through a hadoop tutorial and was able to login into maria_dev and root users inside the sandbox. I went ahead and rest the root user password, which was 'hadoop' earlier.
Now after a long while I forgot the root use password. Could you please let me know how to reset the password?
My environment: Hortonworks HDP 2.5

Answer (score 2):

There are more than one user. `maria_dev` is just the database admin account

There should be another account named `raj_ops`

Otherwise, you'd have to connect into the mysql database for Ambari and start messing with hashed passwords or use the ambari-server CLI

Comment: Actually am trying to reset password for the 'root' user account. Is it something I can do through Ambari UI. Could you please let me know the steps

Comment: The UI will not let you login without a valid password. You will need to use the terminal `ambari-server` command or manually edit the datbase with `mysql`, and `root` cannot be changed by anyone but `root` user

Comment: @OneCricketeer What is the difference between users 'maria_dev' and 'raj_ops'?

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth They have different permission sets on the database... There used to be a HDP docs page that explained the differences. You should be able to use MariaDB commands to inspect the database users and permissions